# REGEX: not include a word between a word sequence

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-group

I need to match a string that includes words in the same order, but not have a specific word.

`name_1 = "Alex Smith"`
`name_2 = "Alex John Smith"`

I want to be able match `Alex Smith`, `Alex Smith jr`, `Alex, Smith II`but not `Alex John Smith` or `Alex John Smith II` ...

I'm trying to get to the regex expression that combines `^(?!.*john).*$` and `/\bAlex\b.*\bSmith\b/`

Comment: With perl/pcre style regexes: `\bAlex\W+Smith\b`